# не переносит строку по enter в Idea как исправить?

Tags: intellij-idea, клавиатура

Случайно нажал какую то комбинацию клавиш, сейчас переносит по контроль + вход (догадался опытным путем). До этого были проблемы с кареткой, этот долбанным прямоугольник появился. Кто его придумал? Убрал в настройках, тоже подскажите каким сочетанием клавиш пользоваться в Idea - платформе на Java

Comment: что указано в File - Settings - Keymap - Editor Actions - Enter?

Comment: Прямоугольник скорее всего стандартный функционал редакторов при нажатии на клавишу `Insert`. Так же можно попробовать сбросить настройки для клавиш Settings->Keymap.

Comment: Не, прямоугольник решается не там. Надо зайти в Setting -> Editor -> Apperance и убрать Use block caret. Вообщем хрен найдёшь. Я уже с этим исправил
А вот с File - Settings - Keymap - Editor Actions - Enter? Там Enter. Хотя вроде работает сейчас проверил. Но туда никогда не заходил.

Answer (score -1):

наверно уже не актуально но

shift + 0

Comment: эм, скобка? как это решает проблему?